# AFNetworking weird error on device, Working on Simulator

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

This is my code for requesting a JSON:

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request


                                  success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){


                                      NSArray *jsonArray =[JSON valueForKey:@"posts"];

                                      [self postsToAnnotations:[self jsonToPosts:jsonArray] andUserLocationLat:lat Lon:lon];


                                  }

                                  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
                                      NSLog(@"response %@",JSON);

                                      NSLog(@"Failed %@",error);

                                      [_activityView removeFromSuperview];


}];

[operation start];
  }
```

It's working fine on simulator for iPhone 5 and in my device (iphone 4) I am getting this error:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x208b9a80 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Apart from that, did you **read** the error message? It's pretty clear from it what the problem is and it's even telling you how you can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the reply of the server which I was not able to see because I was using AFJSONRequestOperation. After sending the same request AFHTTPRequestOperation  I was able to see the reply of the server using "result" string.